# Units of the ring $\{a+b\epsilon:a,b \in k \}$ where $ϵ^2=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm making exercises to prepare for my ring theory exam:

> Let $k$ a field and $R=k[\epsilon]$ the set
>
> $$\{a+b\epsilon:a,b \in k \}$$
>
> where $$(a+bϵ)+(c+dϵ)=(a+c)+(b+d)ϵ \quad \quad\quad
>  (a+bϵ)(c+dϵ)=ac+(bc+ad)ϵ$$
>
> What are the units of this ring ?

After calculation I get that $(a+bϵ)^{-1}=a^{-1}+-ba^{-2}ϵ$. This is only defined if and only if $a≠0$. Is this the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed! Nicely done.${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

For users that are intrested, the steps in my calculation where:

$$(a+bϵ)^{-1}(a-bϵ)^{-1}(a-bϵ) = ((a-bϵ)(a+bϵ))^{-1}(a-bϵ)=(a^2)^{-1}(a-bϵ)=a^{-1}-a^{-2}bϵ$$

Comment: This proves that *if* elements $a+b\epsilon$ with $a\ne0$ are invertible, then their inverse have the form $a^{-1}-a^{-2}b\epsilon$. You're missing the (easy) verification that this is indeed the inverse when $a\ne0$.

Comment: True, good catch. If $a+bϵ$ has an inverse, then $a≠0$. If $a≠0$, then $(a^{-1}+-ba^{-2}ϵ)(a+bϵ)=1$ follows after calculation and noting that $k$ is commutative.